# Android can't find the directory of a file had been put on sd card

Tags: java, android, sd-card

The problem is that I put the file through the DDMS Perspective in data and /data/data folder and when I try to access to that files, the FileNotFoundException occures. 
Code:

```
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/analyzer_settings.xml";
                System.out.println(path);

                try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(path));
                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Exception with print:

```
07-11 17:10:02.470: I/System.out(13506): mounted/analyzer_settings.xml
07-11 17:10:02.500: W/System.err(13506): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mounted/analyzer_settings.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I've tried also:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/data/analyzer_settings.xml";
or 
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/data/data/analyzer_settings.xml";
```

nothing worked for me.

Comment: Make sure that the path is correct.xml file u want to access is under sdcard and not in any folder of sdcard...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
              +"analyzer_settings.xml";
```

instead of

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/analyzer_settings.xml";
```

---

**EDIT:**
Because as doc says:

[getExternalStorageDirectory ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29):

> Gets the Android external storage directory. This directory may not
>   currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their
>   computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has
>   happened. You can determine its current state with
>   getExternalStorageState().

and

[getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29):

> Gets the current state of the primary "external" storage device.

Comment: + 1 for post an answer before me. 10 Second Ahead.

Comment: So should I place the files in /mnt/sdcard instead of /data folder?

Comment: if you have read/write permision in `/data` folder on SDCARD then use as  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
              +"data/analyzer_settings.xml";`

Comment: I've tried to put file into the root of /mnt/sdcard still not working 07-11 18:03:18.931: I/System.out(1020): /mnt/sdcard/data/analyzer_settings.xml
07-11 18:03:18.931: W/System.err(1020): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/data/analyzer_settings.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) and how can I change mode to read/write the file via DDMS Perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Try this coding,

```
       File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File file = new File(sdcard,"billdump1.xml");//Don't use '/' symbols
```

Comment: it Worked :). love the simple answer